# $(document).ready(function() {}); throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just started learning JavaScript, specifically Jquery.

I saw the $(document).ready(function() {}); and put it in my code to see it, 
but when i define it in the header tag of my html, the script tag throws a green error line underneath. If the opening script tag is closed like `<script>`,
it throws a error expecting a type. I put in the type and then decide to remove the end tag from the script so that the code gets picked up and it tells me that it needs the closing > tag.

I dont know what is going on, as i have the code exactly as the example.

I am using visual web developer 2010 express.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Practising Javascript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Practise.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js"> </script>
    <script> type="text/javascript" $(document).ready(function () {}); </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you put `type="text/javascript"` (correctly!) inside the opening tag in the first two cases, but outside of it in the last case. Why should the third one be any different then first two? HTML generally has the form `<tagName attributeName="attributeValue">content</tagName>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Replace

```
<script> type="text/javascript" $(document).ready(function () {}); </script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {}); </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Syntax incorrect and order of inclusion incorrect

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Practise.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { /* YOUR CODE */ }); </script>
```

Take care that jQuery is included **Before** you using it.

Comment: The inclusion is only a problem if _Practise_ requires jQuery...

Comment: I said **before using it**

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude but you also said *order on inclusion incorrect* instead of *order of inclusion **potentially** incorrect* :P

Comment: Just read the last words: `Take care that jQuery is included Before you using it.`. That's the explanation.

Comment: @TimothyGoodes you don't need an external jQuery file, only put it at the first if your `Practise.js` use inside it a jQuery code.